# Connect-SPOService error:Could not load type 'Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials

Tags: powershell, sharepoint

I am trying to connect to SharePoint with Powershell Connect-SPOService
But I get the error:

```
| Could not load type 'Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials' from assembly
     | 'Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime, Version=16.1.0.0, Culture=neutral,
     | PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c'.
```

I reinstalled Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.PowerShell and import it. But still.
I also have PnP.PowerShell installed. can that be the issue?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is due to DLL Version mismatch. To resolve the issue, follow these steps:

1. Uninstall SharePoint Online Management Shell and SharePoint Online Client SDK if installed.
2. Delete SharePoint Online Client Assemblies from: `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL`, Remove all Folders starting with name: `Microsoft.SharePoint*`
3. Uninstall the module with `Uninstall-Module -Name Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.PowerShell` and reinstall the module `Install-Module -Name Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.PowerShell`